# Solve a quartic function with three unknowns and two given roots.

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, quartics

I'd like to know how I could solve the following quartic function: $p(z)=2z^4+az^3+bz^2+cz+3$ given that it $2$ and $i$ should be part of their roots.

I thought I should maybe be trying to turn this into a quadratic function and then I should be able to solve it for the 2 given roots, but I don't really know how I could get there.

Comment: Well, I think The polynomial has factors $(z-2)(z-i)$.

Comment: Yeah, I started by writing that down but I didn't really know what next steps I could take.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ supposed to be real numbers? If yes, then $-i$ will also be a root.

Comment: How does one solve a function?

Comment: @achillehui Yes a, b and c are supposed to be real numbers.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo. For functions of a higher degree like that one I normally use Horner's table to find it's factors.

Comment: In that case, you want to factor, not solve. Recall that polynomials have roots, functions have zeros and equations have solutions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm sorry but could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is to find $a$, $b$ and $c$, then you can substitute the known zeros of $p$ to get a set of linear equations:

$\begin{eqnarray}p(2) & = & 0 & \implies & 2 \times 2^4 + a \times 2^3 + b \times 2^2 + c \times 2 + 3 & = & 0 & \implies 32 + 8a + 4b + 2c + 3 & = & 0\\
p(i) & = & 0 & \implies & 2 \times i^4 + a \times i^3 + b \times i^2 + c \times i + 3 & = & 0 & \implies 2 - ai - b + ci + 3 & = & 0\end{eqnarray}$

Now, you have a few options:

1. Use the knowledge that you have real coefficients to separate the second equation into a real and imaginary part;
2. Use the fact that $p(-i) = 0$, which results from having real coefficients;
3. Get the 4th root using Vieta's formulas, as given in the other answer.

All of these will give you enough information to solve the entire system for the three unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

using Vieta's formulas, and the fact that complex roots occurs in pairs, we get $x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}=x_{1}.2.i.(-i)=(-1)^{n}\frac{a_{0}}{a_{n}}=3/2$. So, $x_{1}=3/4$